# Module name and directory name conflict?

Tags: java, tomcat, puppet, puppet-enterprise

I created a module named 'learn-tomcat' and it has a class named tomcat (in init.pp). When I try to include this class in a node definition, it does not work, all of following combination throw an error, the combinations are:

```
include learn-tomcat::tomcat
include learn-tomcat
include tomcat
include ::tomcat
```

And error is same with above combinations:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not find class
```

Now when I rename module directory learn-tomcat to tomcat, then following start working!

```
include tomcat
include ::tomcat
include tomcat::tomcat
```

Now I am confused about a few things:

- Although Puppet enforces the name of module to be USERNAME-MODULENAME while creating - should one rename it after creation?
- I could not find relevant documentation but what exactly is happening here?

Comment: Looks like this is an known issue with Puppet https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-3124

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have a comprehensive explanation how namespaces and scopes works in [puppet](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_namespaces.html).

According to the example from the article:

```
name:                   file path:
apache                  <modulepath>/apache/manifests/init.pp
apache::mod             <modulepath>/apache/manifests/mod.pp
apache::mod::passenger  <modulepath>/apache/manifests/mod/passenger.pp
```

So in your situation you can also do one of the following suggestion:

1. In module `learn-tomcat` in `init.pp`, rename `tomcat` class to `learn-tomcat`,  and than instance it by:

   `include learn-tomcat`
2. Rename the file `init.pp` to `tomcat.pp` and than instance it by:

   `include learn-tomcat::tomcat`